# Erro de sintaxe socket-python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
  except socket.error, (errno, msg):
            if errno == 1:
                # Operation not permitted
                msg = msg + (
                    " - Note that ICMP messages can only be sent from processes"
                    " running as root."
                )
                raise socket.error(msg)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 699, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 88, in execfile
>       exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)   File "/home/epamos/Downloads/Gping2(1).py", line 78
>       except socket.error, (errno, msg):
>                          ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Estou usando o python 3.5, ao retirar a vírgula há o desencadeamento de 7 erros envolvendo GPing.

Comment: Posta o stack trace completo. Vc pode adicioná-lo clicando em editar.

Comment: E se fizeres `except socket.error as err:` depois deves ajustar. Estou no tele e não consigo testar mas pode ser que resolva

Comment: Infelizmente não resolveu o problema!

Answer (score 2):

Esta sintaxe do Except não é válida em Python 3-  essa é a sintaxe antiga do Python 2, e mesmo em código novo feito para rodar em Python 2 ainda é recomendado que se use o novo estilo:

```
try:
   ...
except NomeDoErro as variavel:
   ...
```

Nesse caso:

```
except socket.error as error:
    # codigo usando a variável error
```

(Nota, eu sugiro que você arrume a identação do seu código Python para usar 4 espaços por bloco, sempre - e não identação variada - vai perceber que fica bem mais fácil de ler)